# How to use NVLink instead of PCIe / Override PCIe Lanes?

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, processor, pcie

Everywhere on internet i read about [NVLink](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvlink.html) is more powerful than PCI lanes connection.

OK, right. But now, i would use this power on my future computer for deeplearning (especially Resnet/TensorFlow training), mainly with GPU scripts based (Cuda). And why not on my current computer.

I'm reflecting about to buy this new base (sorry, i don't have the money to buy a DGX-1, neither a V100):

- MB: ASUS [Z10PE-D8 WS](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Z10PED8_WS/)
- CPU: 2x [Xeon E5-2620 v4](https://ark.intel.com/products/92986/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v4-20M-Cache-2_10-GHz) (40 lanes)
- GPU: 4x [GTX1080Ti](https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N108TAORUSX-WB-11GD#kf) (or more)

But the PCIe is badly limited to x16/x16 with dual gpu, and x8/x8/x8/x8 with quadrial gpu... So, i'm not satisfied at all.

**Is it possible to active NVLink instead of PCIe to improve the performance ?**

**Is there another solution to override/improve the number of lanes ?**

**At least, is there another mobo/cpu supporting x16/x16/x16/x16 with dual CPU ?**

Bios modding or whatever, i would want to go beyond this limit.

Thanks.

---

**[Edit]** The motherboard seems to handle 2 PCIe x16 for each cpu. The i7 are 1S only, i changed to Xeon 2600 v4 series, thanks [Alpha3031](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/203/alpha3031)

---

**[Edit]** Finally, there is no possibility to use nvlink for now, i took a *Supermicro Superserveur 4U 7048GR-TR* with 6 pcie v3 x16/x16/x16/x16/x8/x8 with dual Xeon 2640 v4 and 1080ti gpus

Comment: It's not possible to use i7 CPUs in 2S. You will need to get Xeons, specifically the E5 2600v3 series. Looking at the block diagram in the manual, it is apparent that the motherboard you've chosen can draw 2 x16 PCIe links off *each* CPU, which would appear to meet the requirements you have specified. That said, if you give more details about what your workload entails, perhaps it would be possible to find an even better solution.

Comment: Oh right, the i7 are 1S only.. I can't really quantify the workload, i just want to use the maximum lane to have 4x Gpu at thex max power, i need to be the fastest with deep learning training, that's all.

Comment: I'm going offline now, but your budget and likely frameworks would probably be the most pertinent information. Any other tidbits may still be useful though. Good luck.

Comment: The budget is less than 8000€.
However, it's not clear about the _2 x16 PCIe links off each CPU_, i'm not sure if it is possible yet, if i don't find any notice that say precisely i can use x16/x16 for each cpu, i think that i ll write to asus if i don't find at all. Else, do you know any other mobo brand for this kind of intel base without buying in a big kind of server ?

Comment: You can check the block diagram in the manual. It's in the Support section. Page 190 on my device. I think you could split your questions up and get the full treatment, CPU, MB, GPU, etc, if you could be bothered. Many of the questions on this site do that.

Comment: Ok i ll see, and finally, the  Z10PE-D8 WS seems to support E5 2600 v4 series, thanks